# Angular i18 localize value of interpolated string in template

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

Let's say I have to translations in my angular app xliff `@@field-is-required` which has a string interpolation and `@@lastname` which is a normal translation.

```xml
<trans-unit id="field-is-required" datatype="html">
    <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ fieldName }}"/> is required</source>
    <target><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ fieldName }}"/> ist Pflichtfeld</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="lastname" datatype="html">
    <source>Lastname</source>
    <target>Nachname</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Is there any way to combine `@@field-is-required` with the value of `@@lastname` in a template?

I'm imagining something like:

```html
<div i18n="@@field-is-required">
    {{ '@@lastname' }} is required
</div>
```

I've tried a few combination but nothing worked for me. And the online documentation of Angular i18n is very lacking (`$localize` isn't even explained in depth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a certain set of alternates, Angular suggests an approach like

```html
{name, select, lastName {last name} firstName {first name} other {unknwon}} is required
```

If the last name can be an arbitrary string, you can define it in your component (for example):

```js
const fieldOptions: string[] = [
   $localize`:Last name of a person:Last name`,
   $localize`:First name of a person:First name`,
]
...
let myOption = fieldOptions[0];
```

and finally in the html:

```
<div i18n="@@field-is-required">
    {{myOption}} is required
</div>
```

Comment: Not the solution i was hoping for but i guess it works :) Thanks

Comment: I have yet to find an example with just a placeholder for a simple variable. But nothing